# Solving an ODE in optimal control

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, ordinary-differential-equations, optimal-control, matrix-exponential

I have been learning the basics of optimal control (from [here](https://youtu.be/nyqJJdhReiA)) and have a question about solving a linear ODE. Let's say I have the following system

$$\dot{x} = A x$$

whose solution is

$$x(t) = e^{At} x(0)$$

From what I have been reading, this is difficult to solve, because $e^{At}$ is difficult to evaluate. The only way to evaluate it is to use a Taylor series expansion, but this is difficult to compute in practice.

Therefore, the solution is to represent the state in terms of the eigenvectors of $A$. After doing some algebra, this results in the following solution:

$$x(t) = T e^{Dt} T^{-1} x(0)$$

where $T$ is a matrix of the eigenvectors of $A$, and $D$ is a diagonal matrix of the eigenvalues of $A$.

Apparently, it is easier to now compute $e^{Dt}$ than it was to compute $e^{At}$ because $D$ is diagonal. But I don't understand why this is. Why does computing $e^{At}$ needs the Taylor series expansion, but computing $e^{Dt}$ can be done directly?

Comment: One of your premises is simply incorrect.  There are lots of ways of numerically computing the matrix exponential and some of them are quite efficient in practice.  Computing the matrix exponential with a diagonal matrix is particularly easy- can you derive a formula for it?

Comment: You're assuming that $A$ is diagonalizable. Computing the matrix exponential of Jordan blocks is not as easy, but it's not hard either.

Answer (score 1):

Recall that as you say, $\exp(At)$ is defined by the power series
$$
\exp(At)=\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{t^n}{n!}A^n
$$
Do you see why the powers $A^n$ are easier to compute if $A$ is diagonal?

Comment: Thanks — yes, I can see here why a diagonal matrix is easy to raise to the power n, because you just raise each diagonal element to the power n. So is the main reason why we convert from the original state space into the eigenvector space, just to make these computations faster? Or are there other reasons? It seems to me quite a lot of extra complexity just for the sake of slightly faster computations; or perhaps I am underestimating how many orders in the Taylor expansion are actually required before convergence...

Comment: I don't know what you mean by the last bit. As to whether it is actually worthwhile, if you have diagonalized $A$, then you can literally write down an expression for each term in the above series. If $A$ is any matrix, this can be very hard. Try to write down an expression for a nondiagonal matrix to the 100th power.

Comment: @Karnivaurus and the series as a whole in closed form, should have added that